# Declare string array in constructor

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to declare an string array in the constructor but when I run the code I get an error, however the debugger doesnt point anything out, also the code works fine when not in the constructor. It this part:

```
String [][] studentdetails = new String [5][3];
```

Error when running code with student details array in constructor is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     studentdetails cannot be resolved to a variable
>     studentdetails cannot be resolved to a variable     studentdetails
>   cannot be resolved to a variable
>
> at StudentMarksProgram.MarksInput(StudentMarksProgram.java:58)  at
>   StudentMarksProgram.(StudentMarksProgram.java:37)   at
>   StudentMarksProgram.main(StudentMarksProgram.java:119)

```
import java.util.*;


public class StudentMarksProgram {
    int studentTotal;


    double [] testaverages = new double [3];

    //In this array for student details [x][0] is the student no, [x][1] is the forename of the student, [x][2] is the surname of the student
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    private int [][] marks;


    private double [] studentaverages;

    public StudentMarksProgram() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("How many students are in your class?");
        studentTotal = scanner.nextInt();
        marks = new int [studentTotal][3];
        studentaverages = new double [studentTotal];

        String [][] studentdetails = new String [studentTotal][3];
        //endless for5555 loop created to run the program and any subroutines
        for (int a=0; a<=2;) {
            int input = 0;
            System.out.println("To input marks/student details press 1,");
            System.out.println("To calculate the average press 2");
            System.out.println("To display averages press 3");
            System.out.println("To search data by student number press 4");
            input = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (input) {
            case 1:
                MarksInput();
                break;
            case 2:
                AverageCalculation();
                break;
            case 3:
                AveragePrint();
                break;
            case 4:
                searchStudentNumber();
                break;
```

```
    }
    void MarksInput () {
        for (int i=0; i<studentTotal; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter student number of student " + (i+1) + " : ");
            studentdetails[i][0] = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the first name of student " + (i+1) + " : ");
            studentdetails[i][1] = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the surname of student " + (i+1) + " : ");
            studentdetails[i][2] = scanner.next();
            for (int j=0; j<=2;) {
                System.out.println("Enter marks for student " + (i + 1) + " in assessment " + (j +1));
                marks[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
                if ((marks[i][j] < 41) && (marks[i][j]) >= 0) {
                    j = j +1;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid marks entered - enter a value between 0 and 40 inclusive");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the error? And maybe show more code

Comment: `studentdetails` (as declared) is only visible in the constructor.

Comment: I added more details and code

Comment: Do not put so much code in the constructor, there should be no functionality there only initialisation of instance variables. So no scanner and getting user input etc, it's really wrong.

Answer (score 0):

modify your code like this

```
String [][] studentdetails;
    public StudentMarksProgram() {

    studentdetails = new String [studentTotal][3];
}
```

As elliot mentioned the scope of studentdetails  was inside your constructor. This should resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare your array inside the constructor.
Try declaring it outside and then initializing it inside the constructor